# Put a step that requires different data per secnario in a gherkin background

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am testing an application that is used on airports. For one of my gherkin features I need several scenarios that all perform an action on a flight. Every scenario needs it's own flight, with slightly different data.

Ideally I would like to put the 'create flight' in a background, because every scenario requires a flight. My issue is that this background step would need to use different data for each scenario, and I'm not sure if cucumber supports that.

Simplified, I would like to do something like this:

```
Feature: Arrival flights

Background:
    Given I am logged in to the application
    And a flight is created with the following data
    | Scenario  | Origin     | ETA    | Flightno | Airline
    | 1         | AMS        | 12:00  | 1111     | KM
    | 2         | LIS        | 13:00  | 2222     | TS

Scenario: User is able to open a flight
    When the user opens flight 'Flightno'
    Then flight 'Flightno' is opened

Scenario: User is able to open the open a flight
    When the user opens flight 'Flightno'
    And the user clicks the 'edit flight' button
    Then the edit flight interface is opened for flight 'Flightno'
```

Re-using the same flight is not an option, neither is using a scenario outline

Can anyone advise a good way of doing this, without having to put the 'create flight' step in every scenario?

If there is no way to do this, and 'create flight' has to be  in every scenario, can someone advise what keyword I should use to start this step? Since creating the flight is not actually what I want to test, I would say it is a 'Given'. But since my background already starts with 'Given', that would lead to 2 'Given' steps.

I could put 'And' in front of it, but that would make the scenario itself start with 'And', which I think looks a bit strange.
I know that technically this doesn't make any difference, but I would like to know what the accepted way of doing this is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an artifact from simplifying the problem, but the details in your examples are mostly spurious. You need not mention them at all because they are not relevant to the scenario.

Without losing any thing you could write your scenario as:

```
Feature: Arrival flights

  Scenario: User is able to open a flight
    Given there is flight
    When the user opens the flight
    Then flight is opened

  Scenario: User is able to open the open a flight
    Given there is flight
    When the user opens the flight
    Then user clicks the 'edit flight' button
    And the edit flight interface is opened for the flight
```

In the `there is flight` step you would create a flight with random but unique data and you'd keep a reference to that flight somewhere. In the next steps that reference "the flight" you then use that flight you created.

Organizing this contextual data may take some work, but have a look at the screen play pattern to make that easier.

https://cucumber.io/blog/bdd/understanding-screenplay-(part-1)/

Also note that you don't need to mention you are logged in every time. It's perfectly okay to do that as part of the `user opens the flight` step.

Comment: Thanks for these insights, this will surely help me tackle this scenario